# Property transfers in soapui

Tags: xml, soapui

I'm trying to write parallel tests in soapui and need to transfer properties between the test steps

I currently have 3 tests steps:

1. Execute legacy request
2. Execute new request
3. XML diff the two responses in a groovy script

I've found a lot of blogs about picking values out with xpaths, but nothing about passing the full response through.

My questions is how do I fill out the source and target boxes in the property transfer editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a "Properties" test step.
2. Add properties for each response.
3. Define a "Property transfer" after each request
4. Set the source to the response of the test step
5. Set the target to the property defined in step 3
6. Access them in groovy like so:

   def props = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
   def response1 = props.getPropertyValue("response1")
   def response2 = props.getPropertyValue("response2")
   println response1
   println response2